# My palindrome checker isn't working on some but does on others? (JAVA)

Tags: java, stack

I'm trying to write a method that takes a queue of integers as a parameter and checks if the queue is palindrome or not.

My method seems to work for most queues but doesn't for others? And I cannot identify a characteristic of those that it doesn't work with...

here is my code:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(Queue<Integer> q) {
    boolean result = false;
    Stack<Integer> save = new Stack<Integer>();

    if(q.isEmpty()){
        result = true;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < q.size(); i++){
      int n = q.remove();
        save.push(n);
        q.add(n);
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < q.size(); j++){
        int a = q.remove();
        int b = save.pop();
        if(a == b){
            result = true;
        } 
             q.add(a);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your code wasn't very well formatted, please format it properly for subsequent questions - Thanks ;-)

Comment: Just joined the site, sorry. I'll get better.

Comment: No problem at all (welcome by the way!), it's just hard to read that way ;-) I formatted it for you.

Comment: Could you add examples where your code works and examples where your code does not work? It will be easier to debug that way

Comment: You should probably start with `result = true` and use `if (a != b) result = false;`

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to create an array from the Queue (Integer[] numbers; q.toArray(numbers);  and then check the values in this Integer array to see if they are palindromatic? (something like: for (int i=0; i < numbers.length/2; i++) {if (numbers[i] != numbers[numbers.length - 1 -i) {result = false; break}

Comment: It works fine with this: [3, 8, 17, 9, 17, 8, 3]

Comment: And does NOT work with, say, this queue: [3, 8, 17, 9, 4, 17, 8, 3]

Comment: Assylias has it right! I'm not entirely sure how it makes a difference..? Maybe just boolean zen? Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that everything is correct except the second for loop. You need to change to check if the content of stack and queue are different. If so, then return `false`. And at the end of the method, return `true`.

```
for (int j = 0; j < q.size(); j++) {
            int a = q.remove();
            int b = save.pop();
            if (a != b) {
                return false;
            }
            q.add(a);
        }
        return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the input queue: [1,1,2]

The stack `save` created by the method will be [2,1,1]

In the 2nd `for` loop, for `j=1`, then `a == b == 1`, and the method wrongly claims a palindrome. Generally, the method will fail where the queue and the stack have the same value at their respective indices. (e.g. The input [4,2,2,5])

There are multiple issues, but the primary one is that once the method claims a palindrome, the assertion is fixed. As mentioned in the comments, it is better to assume the input is not a palindrome, and then prove it.

Answer (score 0):

In your second for loop, you have

```
if(a == b){
    result = true;
}
```

However, at no point in the rest of the loop could it ever become false again.  This means that, given a queue of length n, if the ith element and the (n-i)th element are the same, then the result will be true.  A Queue of {1, 3, 5, 1} would return true for example.

A better implementation would be more intuitive to how you would check it using pen and paper.
You only need to check every ith and (n-i)th element until you find one that does not 
make it a palindrome.  If you check the entire queue with no errors, then you have a palindrome!

Here's one way you can do it:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(Queue<Integer> q) {
    Stack<Integer> save = new Stack<Integer>();

    if(q.isEmpty()){
        return true;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < q.size(); i++){
      int n = q.remove();
        save.push(n);
        q.add(n);
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < q.size(); j++){
        int a = q.remove();
        int b = save.pop();
        if(a != b){
            return false; // cannot be a palindrome
        } 
        q.add(a);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: how would u do this question without using a for loop and preserving the original queue?